# What do the following command in detail du -s * | sort -nr > $HOME/space_report.txt?

Tags: 14.04

What do the following command in detail? `du -s * | sort -nr > $HOME/space_report.txt`

Comment: They make you read `man du`, `man sort` and `man bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command shows the size of all the individual files and directories in your current directory (most likely your home directory or ~/).

Next, `sort -nr` sorts the results by number and then reverses those results to show the largest files or directories first, down to the smallest ones and prints the results to a file named `space_report.txt` in your home directory.

To view the results, you can run one of the following commands:

```
cat ~/space_report.txt
```

or

```
less ~/space_report.txt
```

Personally, I would use this instead because it prints the file size in a human readable form:

```
du -hsx * | sort -rh > $HOME/space_report.txt
```

Again, to view the file:

```
less ~/space_report.txt
```

or

```
less ~/space_report.txt
```

If you don't want to print to a file, you could just run this instead:

```
du -hsx * | sort -rh
```

---

To figure this out on your own, all you have to do is type:

```
du --help
```

and look for the -s flag to see what it is for.

Then, do the same for sort:

```
sort --help
```

and look for the -n flag and the -r flag.

For more information, you can run the following:

```
man du
```

or

```
man -Hfirefox du
```

and

```
man sort
```

or

```
man -Hfirefox sort
```

Comment: @zzzach you are right, I accidentally rejected that edit. Thanks!

Comment: thnx u so much u saved my life lol. I need this for my home work.

Comment: @alfonsbara if this answers your question, don't forget to click the icon to the left to accept this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: @michid, done.  i have and other question to if u can i will be glad if u can answer.

Comment: @alfonsbara just ask it as another question

Comment: i have post it. cheek it if u can it is my lest question. what do: sudo find / -type f \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -print ? why is it interesting to know? this is the question